Pin "how to ask" to the "asking questions" column on the SO help center's home page?
New user welcome comments
A frequent comment I have added to questions from new users is to direct them to the SO site tour, the SO help center and the "How do I ask a good question?" article. Typically this occurs for users with a reputation of 1 who haven't taken the tour (what tour?) and as put in this answer to a similar question:

"have not missed a little detail, but simply have absolutely no idea about how to ask for help"

An example of such a comment I made earlier today can be found here.
Requested change
I would like to suggest/request moving the link to "How do I ask a good question" from below the "view more" details line on the SO help center's home page and pin it in the same "asking" column, preferably at the top, or failing that above the 3rd entry for What does it mean if a question is "closed"?.
In the process I would suggest renaming the page to "How to ask a good question" instead of "How should I ask a good question".
Background

While not asking to unpin it, I've never had or seen the need to provide links to "what does it mean if my question is closed",
The asking column is shorter than the column to its right and shouldn't need cropping.
IHMO directing a new user to "how to ask a good question" is more  encouraging, friendly and helpful than telling them to read something called "How do I ask a good question".


I agree with this, except for this part: "In the process I would suggest renaming the page to 'How to ask a good question' instead of 'How should I ask a good question'." Putting aside the fact that the title is actually "How do I ask a good question?" (also note the question mark), why is this better?  You state that it's "more encouraging, friendly and helpful", but it's not clear to me why that would be.  Note that the other articles in that list are all phrased as questions as well.

Practically what grinds my gears is that the help center is so fragmented. We have an article for what you can ask, an article for what you can't ask and an article for what is a good idea to ask. And they expect people to actually read any of it, let alone comprehend it?

@Gimby I agree. I posted this suggestion as an attempt to make it easier for new users know that guidelines are available. To be honest a well written index or introduction with links may even be better, providing a quick list of guidelines for "how to ask", "How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML",  "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" etc. And perhaps mention that after copying and pasting error message text the OP should indicate which line of code produced it!

@RyanM For me "How do I write a good question?" contains an implicit criticism that I have presented a bad question, that I should have known better and it's somehow my fault. Blame it on some narcissistic parenting if you will, but given the number of people who never quote the actual title when providing a link to it I doubt I am alone in thinking that we can do better than the "How do I ask a good question? " phraseology.
